# Construction of a sequence of measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Is there any sequence $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ of measurable functions such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R},\lim_nf_n(x)=x$ such that there exist a nonempty bounded interval $C_n=[\alpha_n,\beta_n]$ where $f_n$ is zero?

Comment: What about $f_\epsilon(x) = ||x| - \epsilon|$ outside of $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ and $0$ on this interval?

Comment: Doesn't converges to $x$ when $\epsilon \to \infty$

Comment: Can’t you simply multiply your limit function $f(x) = x$ by characteristic functions for increasing intervals? On the complements of these intervals (which contain intervals) your functions will be zero.

Comment: Ah yes, for some reason I was thinking about $|x|$ and not $x$. But multiplying by $\operatorname{sgn} x$ solves this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance:$$f_n(x)=x\left(1-\mathsf1_{[0,\frac1{n}]}(x)\right)$$**Addendum**:

Another example is:$$f_n(x)=x\left(1-\mathsf1_{[n,e^n]}(x)\right)$$
with shifting interval increasing in length.

Comment: Slip of pen. Is this what you are after then?

Comment: Ok. I was wandering if there was an example where $\beta_n \to +\infty$ and $\alpha_n \to -\infty$

Comment: @john I’m not sure what you mean exactly. If $\beta_n \to +\infty$ and $\alpha_n \to \infty$, no such sequence can exist (your intervals will always contain $[-1, 1]$ once $n$ is big enough).

Comment: If you just want your intervals to have increasing length, you can make them bigger and shift them to (say) $+ \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ but then your lower bound won’t go to $- \infty$.